# How to use npm in WebStorm when you have a proxy set up?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, http-proxy

I am trying to install packages using the node package manager in WebStorm IDE, however I am getting a 407 proxy authentication required error.

I have tried to set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables under the npm settings but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone else had similar issues and if so how did you get around them?